# Reducing induced width of set membership graph

Tags: algorithm, set, graph-theory

I have a number of sets, and a related graph where set elements are connected if they are in a set with each other. I need to find an ordering for the set elements which will result in a low induced width for the graph (I understand that finding the ordering that yields the minimal induced width is np-hard).

1. What is the best heuristic for ordering a graph to get a low induced width?
2. Is there a way to find a good ordering without generating the actual graph and working directly from the sets?

I'm doing this because I'm trying to implement an algorithm which is exponential on the induced width of the ordering chosen.

Edit: some definitions.

**Ordered graph** - the graph mentioned above, with a total ordering applied to the nodes.

**Parent node** - For a given node, an adjacent node which precedes the node in the ordering is a parent of that node.

**Induced graph** - The graph obtained by adding an edge between any two nodes that are parents of the same node.

**Width of an ordered graph** - The greatest number of parents any node in the ordered graph has.

**Induced width** - Width of the induced graph.

Comment: By width do you mean treewidth? There's a high-degree polynomial algorithm to compute the optimal branchwidth, which works for many of the same things. Alternatively, you might look into spectral partitioning.

Comment: @user635541 I don't think that's the same thing. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_graph For a given ordering of nodes in a graph, connect nodes when they are parents of the same node, to get the induced graph. The width of this induced graph is the induced width.

Comment: What do you mean by ordering the graph? My understanding from your phrasing is that the graph has one node per element, and an edge between two nodes if the two elements co-occur in at least one set; is there another graph I am missing?

Comment: @mitchus That is the only graph. I want to then _assign_ a strict total order to the nodes/elements, and look at its induced width.

Comment: in that case, could you explain what you mean by "induced witdh"? Is it the maximum difference in ranks between two linked nodes?

Comment: I have edited the question with some definitions I hope will make the problem clearer.